# Generic method with Future return, says return of invalid type

Tags: flutter, dart

This code block works:

```
Future<XData?> getXData(String id) async {
try {
   var response =  await xService.getXResponse();
   return response.data;
 } catch (exception) {
 return null;
 }
}
```

But this one is not. It says return of invalid type. Why?

```
@override
Future<XData?> getXData<XData>(String id) async {
try {
   var response =  await xService.getXResponse();
   return response.data;
 } catch (exception) {
 return null;
 }
}
```

This is the overriden method:

```
  Future<T?> getXData<T>(String id);
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show the full code for the class you are overriding?

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, `XData` works as stand-in type for generics, not for the actual `XData` type. Basically it's the same as writing:

```dart
Future<T?> getXData<T>(String id) async {
```

If you're in an IDE like VSCode you can verify by Ctrl+click on the XData, and you won't go anywhere except the definition of `XData` in that line. Now do that again with the first snippet, Ctrl+clicking on `XData` will bring you to the class definition.

So the correct way of overriding the method is like the first snippet.

More on generics: https://dart.dev/language/generics